# Media Query For Samsung Galaxy S10 Not Working

Tags: css, media-queries, samsung-galaxy

I can't get the media query for my Samsung Galaxy S10 to work. I've used the following code but it's like my actual phone/device is completely ignoring it:

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 360px) and (min-device-height: 760px) and (orientation: portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 4) {}
```

The above isn't working though. I also tried going to mydevice.io on my S10, but it shows my viewport width is 412px and when turned landscape it's 778px so I thought I could use those as the width and height, but that didn't work either.

Comment: Having the same issue here with Galaxy S10e on Android 9 (European mobile).
I was pretty sure media queries used to work in the past for this client (can't say 100% for sure). What I'm trying is: `@media screen and (max-width: 640px) {
  p {
    color: red !important;
}`   The former code is not working